# How to use the "Paste Formatting" function via Keyboard in PowerPoint?

Tags: macos, microsoft

In Powerpoint 2013 (Windows) there is a function "Paste formatting only" (Ctrl + Shift + V) that will apply formatting of the object in the clipboard to the currently selected object (see [list of shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Use-keyboard-shortcuts-to-create-your-presentation-ebb3d20e-dcd4-444f-a38e-bb5c5ed180f4?ui=en-US)).

In Powerpoint 2011 (Mac) so far I could not find a similar function (see [list of shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/PowerPoint-keyboard-shortcuts-f25f92b3-b0a8-4c60-aec8-954b72aa81ad?ui=en-US)).

Does such a command exist and is there a way to use it with keyboard shortcuts? Can it maybe simulated with a VBA macro?